# How to do SMA Crossover within last n days?

Tags: pine-script

How to do SMA Crossover within last n days ?

e.g close cross above 20 day within last 10 trading days

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
numBars = input(title="Number of days", type=integer, defval=20, minval=1, maxval=300)

sma = sma(close, numBars)


// the next two string are used in case the chart's resolution differs from daily
securDaily = security(tickerid, 'D', close)
daylyRes = period == 'D' ? close : securDaily


crossed = 0
for i = 0 to numBars
    if crossover(sma[i], daylyRes[i])
        crossed := 1
        break

plot(crossed)
```

The for-loop is helpful in such situation.